# Extraction of data from column using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column named device name which has data like:

```
Drivers/BacnetIdentifiers/FP VeV 4-01 Training Lobby
Drivers/BacnetIdentifiers/FP CaV 4-01 Training Lobby
Drivers/BacnetIdentifiers/FP altu 4-01 auditorium
Drivers/BacnetIdentifiers/devicegn/FP altu 4-01 auditorium
```

It needs to extract the data after the last "/" using SQL.
Can someone please help here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT SUBSTR
       (
            "device" ,
            INSTR("device" , '/', -1)+1,
            INSTR("device" , '/', -1)
       )
FROM   Devices
```

Explanation:

`SUBSTR` : This is a function that returns a part of a string. It takes the following 3 arguments

`Initial string` : This is the string of which you need to take a part. In your case this is your table column.

`Start Index`: This is the index of the initial string that your part should start.

`Length`: This is the length of the part you want to return.

**Example**

```
SUBSTR('ABCDEF',3,2) -- Returns 'CD'
```

Will get 2 characters starting from the third of the string 'ABCDEF'.

To return in your case, the `Initial string` is your table column. 
The `Start index` should be the last index (last occurrence) of the character '/'. In order to find this we will use the following function:

`INSTR`: It is a function that returns the location of a string in a string and has the following arguments:

`Initial string`: This is the string within which you want to find a substring

`substring` : This is what you are searching for.

`Start position`: At which location of the first string you start your search. If this is a negative number then you are starting from the end of the string to the start. In your case we search the first occurrence of '/' from the end of your string.

**Example**

```
INSTR('Drivers/BacnetIdentifiers/FP VeV 4-01 Training Lobby' , '/', -1) -- Returns 26
```

This will return 27 which is the first occurence of the character '/' from the end of the string

`LENGTH` : Is a function that returns the length of a specified string.

**Example**

```
LENGTH('ABCDEF') -- Returns 6
```

Combining all these we say that we want a **number of charachters** after the last occurrence of '/' within the value of our column.

Comment: Check my edit for more info. I also found a logic error that while working was an added pain.

Answer (score 0):

`regexp_replace(your_string, '^.*/')`

Comment: this will be a column name. i cannot determine the data before hand.